# Python change locale with arrow

Tags: python, string, datetime, arrow-python

I have a date string: "Viernes 24 de Octubre". I want to change it to arrow datetime object.
also i have installed es locales: `sudo apt-get install language-pack-es-base`
This doesn't work:

```
print arrow.get('Viernes 24 Octubre', 'dddd D MMMM', locale='es')
```

Thank you

Comment: related `arrow` bug: [locale argument not respected for month names in `arrow.get()`](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow/issues/61)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`arrow.parser.DateTimeParser()` uses `calendar.month_name[1:]`](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow/blob/2876bf8582a8/arrow/parser.py#L33) to parse month names i.e., you need to set locale before calling `arrow.get()`:

```
import calendar
import locale

print(calendar.month_name[10])
# -> October
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8') # system-dependent locale name
print(calendar.month_name[10])
# -> Octubre
```

Note: changing the locale affects the whole program.